# jQuery categorised functions

Tags: jquery

I want to categorised functions in same objects to increase readability. But I do not know how to do it?

```
$.forms = function () {
  addField = function(e) {};
};
```

How can I access addField in button's onClick event?

```
<button onclick="$.forms.addField(this);">Press me!</button>
```

it does not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `$.forms` to be an object not a function. Try the following:

```
$.forms = {
    addField: function(e) {

    }
};
```

This will turn the `$.forms` in to an object as you want it to be.

**Edit:** But if you want to keep it as a function you will have to write it as:

```
$.forms = function ()
{
    return 
    {
        addField: function(e)
        {

        }
    };
};
```

And use it as:

```
$.forms().addField(e)
```

Comment: what is the difference between, as a function or object ? Is there any disadvantages if i keep it as an object ?

Comment: @GoMommy For what you want to achieve, an object would be better. Function should be used when there is some processing required before initiating the object. Like, some external variable with local scope.